# How can i make fields and methods of a sub class usable to a class which only uses the super class through another class

Tags: java, inheritance

So, after some hours searching through the forum for the answer i am searching for i couldn't find anything that helps me so here i go.

I am trying to make a Monopoly style game and i am making the Game Engine class.
I have a 'Board' class and an 'abstract Card' class which i use to make several other classes such as 'HouseCard', 'Decision Card', 'AirportCard' etc.
As you can see every card class has different methods and fields.
I am trying to make the game engine class right now and i need to access some of the fields and some of the methods of some of those classes but i can't. The only possible solution Eclipse gives me is to make the methods inside the 'Abstract Card' class and the do an @Override in the sub classes but this is not right because i will have to implement those methods inside all other classes so in the end i will have like 30 methods in every class which is wrong.
I am providing some code to see what i mean because i have done this solution to two abstract Boolean methods and one int and already it feels wrong.

This is the Card class:

```
public abstract class Card {
    
    public Card() {
    }
    
    public void stringCard() {
    }
    
    public void setHolder(int holderID) {
    }
    
    public abstract Boolean hasOwner();
    public abstract Boolean buyable();
    public abstract int getBuyCost();
}
```

This is the one of the card sub classes i use 'HouseCard' class:

```
public class HouseCard extends Card{
    
    public String cardName;
    public int buycost, rent, h1, h2, h3, h4, hotel, mortgage, hcost;
    public int holderID = -1;
    
    public HouseCard(String cardName, int buycost, int rent, int h1, int h2, int h3, int h4, int hotel, int mortgage, int hcost) {
        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.buycost = buycost;
        this.rent = rent;
        this.h1 = h1;
        this.h2 = h2;
        this.h3 = h3;
        this.h4 = h4;
        this.hotel = hotel;
        this.mortgage = mortgage;
        this.hcost= hcost;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setHolder(int holderID) {
        this.holderID = holderID;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean buyable() {
        if (this.holderID == -1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public Boolean hasOwner() {
        if (this.holderID == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getBuyCost() {
        return buycost;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void stringCard() {
        System.out.println("      " + cardName + " (" + buycost + "$)");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Rent Pay    -> " + rent + "$");
        System.out.println("1st House   -> " + h1 + "$");
        System.out.println("2nd House   -> " + h2 + "$");
        System.out.println("3rd house   -> " + h3 + "$");
        System.out.println("4th house   -> " + h4 + "$");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Hotel       -> " + hotel + "$");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Mortgage    -> " + mortgage + "$");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    
    public String getCardName() {
        return cardName;
    }
}
```

And this is the board class i use to store every square in my game using different methods for different cards:

```
public class Board {
    
    public ArrayList<Card> Cards;
    public int numberBoard = 0;
    
    public Board(){
        this.Cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }
    
    public void addCard(String cardName, String cardDesc) {
        Card card = new GeneralCard(cardName, cardDesc);
        Cards.add(card);
        numberBoard++;
    }
    
    public void addCard(String cardName, String cardDesc, Action action) {
        Card card = new GeneralCard(cardName, cardDesc, action);
        Cards.add(card);
        numberBoard++;
    }
    
    public void addCardMulti(String cardName, int buycost, int pay1, int pay2, int mortgage) {
        Card card = new MultiCard(cardName, buycost, pay1, pay2, mortgage);
        Cards.add(card);
        numberBoard++;
    }
    
    public void addCardAirport(String cardName, int buycost, int air1, int air2, int air3, int air4, int mortgage) {
        Card card = new AirportCard(cardName, buycost, air1, air2, air3, air4, mortgage);
        Cards.add(card);
        numberBoard++;
    }
    
    public void addCardHouse(String cardName, int buycost, int rent, int h1, int h2, int h3, int h4, int hotel, int mortgage, int hcost) {
        Card card = new HouseCard(cardName, buycost, rent, h1, h2, h3, h4, hotel, mortgage, hcost);
        Cards.add(card);
        numberBoard++;
    }
}
```

And here are some lines i have to use fields and methods from the sub classes Cards. As you can see in the first line where i use the abstract method `getBuyCost()` it works fine but at the second line where i use `getCardName()`, which is a method used in the sub class only without having it in the Card super class it doesn't work.

```
dashboard.Cards.get(Players.get(i).getSquare()).getBuyCost();


System.out.println(Players.get(i).getName() + " bought " + dashboard.getCard(Players.get(i).getSquare()).getCardName() + " successfully.");
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: For ease of posting, I recommend copy/paste the code into the textbox and then highlight the copied code then hitting the Code button (looks like `{}`) at the top of the editor. That will properly space it to go into the code boxes.

Comment: @TimHunter thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `getCardName()` method is not defined in your `Card` class. Since that variable seems like data that would apply to all your subclasses I recommend moving it up into the parent `Card` class.

```
public abstract class Card {
  private String cardName;

  public Card(String cardName) {
     this.cardName = cardName;
  }

  public String getCardName() {
    return cardName;
  }

  //Other methods
}
```

Then your subclasses can call the `super()` method to set that value when they are instantiated.

```
public class HouseCard extends Card {
  public HouseCard(String cardName) {
    super(cardName);
  }
}
```

And then you won't have any issues calling the `getCardName()` method on a `Card` object since you defined what that is in the `Card` parent class. You can also then call the `getCardName()` method inside your subclasses to get the value in this context (or use the `protected` keyword instead of `private` for the variable if you wanna just reference it directly).

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return getCardName() + " some other info specific to this class"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped me.

Comment: @Kamora Sure thing, mate. Hope the rest of your project goes well!

Comment: Thanks! Have a nice day.

Comment: the solution you gave is for one field only? If you see the code in the Board class i am making a square with many different fields. Should i do something different for that because currently i cant make it work.

Comment: @Kamora Not sure I understand what you mean? If a variable can apply to all subclass then it should be in the parent class. If it's not applicable to all then it should be in the subclass. If you need to access a variable unique to a subclass, then you need to take the `Card` object and cast it into the subclass using the technique fsimon showed you. You can treat the `super()` method the same as calling the constructor of the parent class, meaning you can set multiple variables through it like a regular constructor. The `super()` class does need called before setting subclass variables.

Comment: @Kamora You can also use the `instanceof` keyword ([examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-instanceof-and-its-applications/)) to check whether the `Card` object is an instance of a specific subclass before trying the cast. Otherwise, you can consider making an enum with the different card types as a variable in the `Card` object and make sure that gets set when making the cards. Then you would just need to check which value the enum is to know what it should be cast as.

Comment: What i mean is that if you go back to my code, in the board class i have a method called addCardHouse(String cardName, int buycost, int rent, int h1, int h2, int h3, int h4, int hotel, int mortgage, int hcost)
How am i suppose to do this action if i transfer some of the fields to the super class?

Comment: @Kamora By passing the ones handled by the parent class into the `super()` method and setting the rest specific to a subclass as normal. `public ChildConstructor(int parentParam1, int parentParam2, int childParam1, int childParam2){ super(parentParam1, parentParam2); this.childParam1 = childParam1; this.childParam2 = childParam2; }`

Comment: Ok now i understand what you mean.
Although later in my program i want to use a field or a method that its not in every sub class which means its a child field and child method. Still it doesn't work because the card class doesn't know about those methods and fields. How can i get them?

Comment: @Kamora I just told you how in my previous comments. You use the casting method fsimon mentioned. Use the `instanceof` keyword to check which subclass it might be before casting (or use a enum variable like I also mentioned above).

Comment: Omg i just understand it. Thanks a lot man you made it really clear for me. Sorry if i made it a little difficult for you but it felt really difficult at the start. Again thanks for your time!

Comment: @Kamora Sure thing. As a design recommendation, you may want to keep separate collections in your `Board` for the different card types so you don't have to fuss with casting too much. You don't need to keep all your `Card` subclasses in the same collection. It's still useful to make use of a `Card` parent class to reduce repeated code even if you only actually manage and manipulate collections of the subclasses during gameplay.

Comment: I will try that but i think right now i have separated the classes with different packages so i don't get confused with the use of each one and also i need differentiate them for later because i want to add swing library functions so its more game looking.

Comment: Is there a way to contact you personally, via email or something else?

Comment: @Kamora https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218985/room-for-tim-hunter-and-kamora

Answer (score 1):

First, you should set HouseCard attributes as private, if you want to respect encapsulation and use your accessor methods.

Second, remember to share all the code related so we can help you better. I will assume `Players.get(i).getSquare` returns an instance of `HouseCard` in your code.

And finally, if `square` attribute is type of `Card`, you will need to make cast of `HouseCard` before calling the `getCardName()` method.

You will end up having something like this:

```
HouseCard card = (HouseCard) Player.get(i).getSquare();
String cardName = card.getCardName();
```

Comment: Sorry that i couldn't provide more code but the Players.get(i).getSquare() returns and integer of the square the player is on.
Besides that i understood what you meant and i will see if i can use this solution too